# How to insert input in a website and get the resulted new URL using my java code?

Tags: java, url

please help me in this , i'm developing a java program that is supposed to enter a website and then search in this website for specific words , then get the results  . my problem is that i don't know how to enter this input in the search bar in the website and what to do to make it go to the next page .

Comment: Show some code what you have created for doing this

Comment: Without more information, how can we possibly even begin to try to help you?  "My car is broken!  Why?"

Comment: You are right , so you can see the code below : 
String s = "nokia 3310";

            URL url = new URL("http://www.gsmarena.com/");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write("sName" + s);
            out.close();

Comment: after writing this piece of code i read the page content and i found that the page still the same , you like i didn't entered an input in the search bar

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the page you have to manipulate the URL to get the right result.

I have searched for `nokiabla` and got this URL

```
http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName=nokiabla
```

So basically you have to do this:

```
String s = "nokia 3310"; 
URL url = new URL("http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName="+s); 
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 
// do the read stuff.
```

You can't just simply write to the URL, how should the webserver handle this? There are many layers between a HTML form and a TCP stream.
You should read abit more about it though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can help you you. It is capable of simulating a browser in Java. There's an example of submitting a form on the [Getting started page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html).